# Is there a way to backup my own contributions?

Tags: support

Sometimes questions get removed by the OP or for any other reasons.

In some cases, I would like to preserve my answer (for future use). In other cases, I would like to preserve my comments.

In this [particular case](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19612/meaning-of-as-to-be?noredirect=1#comment36424_19612), for example, I would ask myself the question again, and for that it would help if I could read the original question and the comments I wrote.

For reasons like the above, I would like to keep a copy of all the contributions I've been involved with. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: If you have T-SQL-fu you can go to [http://data.stackexchange.com/], click on the ELL link, and compose queries to recover Posts and Comments linked to your ELL Users.Id (which is 4559). The database schema is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede). The data you fetch can be downloaded in CSV format. Deleted Posts/Comments may have the OwnerUserId/UserId deleted - I'm not sure - but you can also ask for records with your OwnerDisplayName/UserDisplayName.

Comment: @StoneyB I don't think deleted data is accessible from the data explorer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157462/  It's also excluded from the data dumps: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33568/

Comment: @snailplane Looks like you're right - I can't retrieve even comments via 'Nico'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the question is gone, it's gone – although after you earn sufficient rep (2000 pts), you'll be able to view deleted questions.

In the meantime, I don't see any harm in giving you this information now.

**Here was the question:**

> More than a decade later, about the time that our feudalism was in the last throes of existence, Carl Marx, writing his Capital, called the attention of his readers to the peculiar advantage of studying the social and political
>   institutions of feudalism, **as then to be seen** in living form only in Japan. [Source](http://www.sacred-texts.com/shi/bsd/bsd06.htm)

I don't understand this "as" structure.
Is this grammatical English?

**Here are the comments you made:**

- what trips me is not the "as" structure, but "to be seen". I'm wondering if "as then to be seen in living form only in Japan" means "as then seen in living form only in Japan".
- [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+to+be&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0) hints "as to be" is an expression falling in disuse.
- from the uses linked from the ngram, I would guess the meaning is something similar to "that were then seen in living form only in Japan". "as to be" seems to be equivalent to "that is/are/was/were/..." depending on the context. I hope someone more knowledgeable than me writes a proper answer.

---

Or, you can try StoneyB's cool trick.